# Objective-C: Will super send a message to the overwritten sub-method?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I am implementing view controllers that shall have different behaviour. They have a common base class, which we will call "SuperClass".

In SuperClass there is a method A which sends a message to method B.
Let's say i create a SubClass and overwrite B.

If i now create an instance of SubClass and call A, will A call B from SuperClass or from SubClass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B from SubClass